# Karnaugh map software for Ubuntu that accepts formula

Tags: software-recommendation

Anybody knows of a Karnaugh map software for Ubuntu where I can input a Boolean formula e.g A+B(C+D) and the software translates it into a Karnaugh map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use karnaugh map minimizer (**KMAP**)

Read more about [here](http://k-map.sourceforge.net/)

download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/k-map/files/k-map/0.4/kmap-04-source.zip/download?use_mirror=garr&download=)

Also you can use Karnaugh Map Analyzer

read about [here](http://www.download32.com/karnaugh-map-analyzer--linux--i161941.html)

downlaod from [here](http://www.download32.com/go/161941/http://www.kma.logicminimizer.com/download/Karnaugh-Map-Analyzer1.0.tar.gz/)

**Hint**: You can still use the windows tools you know using **Wine**

Comment: Thanks. Karnaugh Map Analyzer contains the functionalities I was searching for.

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice time

Answer (score 0):

I googled "Karnaugh map tools" and found this website:

http://courseware.ee.calpoly.edu/~rsandige/KarnaughExplorer.html

It will run on Ubuntu of course, but it does require you to be online. Also it supports only up to 4 variables.

There's also this one that *should* run on Ubuntu, though I didn't really try it:

http://k-map.sourceforge.net/

You may have some luck looking in Google results.